# Flutter: How do I call a function in widget A from widget B when the widgets do not have a parent/child relationship?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, just-audio

I have the following structure for my app, where ChatScreen contains the ChatHeader and the ChatFooter.

```
                   ---ChatHeader.dart --- MessageDao.dart
ChatScreen.dart ---
                   ---ChatFooter.dart
```

In the ChatHeader widget, I call another widget called MessageDao.dart. This widget generates the button that the user can press on the ChatHeader widget to play audio.

In the ChatFooter widget, this widget contains a different button that the user can press to record using their mic.

When I play audio using the button from ChatHeader -> MessageDao, this works just fine. However, if I click the button in the ChatFooter widget to start recording while *in the middle of playing audio from the first button*, this audio doesn't stop playing. It keeps playing while I'm recording. I have a stopPlaying() function in MessageDao that I can use, but I'm not sure how to call a function in widget A from widget B.

Or in other words, how do I call MessageDao.stopPlaying() from inside ChatFooter.dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this type of situation, the ideal solution is to take a page out of React and '**lift the state up**'; this means that whatever method is on the child should be lifted to a higher node in the widget tree (e.g. `ChatScreen`) and then pass the function down to the nodes that use it (`ChatHeader` and `ChatFooter`). You could also try leveraging `InheritedWidget` after 'lifting state up' and avoid sending methods down a chain of widgets.

Now, this is a recurring theme with Flutter apps (and overall declarative frameworks) and is a problem that can have multiple solutions. My suggestion would be that you take a look at different state management options like `bloc`, `provider`, `mobx`, `riverpod`, `rxdart`, `redux` or `event_bus_plus` just to mention a few. Said libraries will give you the abstractions you need for each use case and help you avoid implementing really complex logic that you might need to solve problems similar to this one by yourself.

Of course, this is an important decision for your project so I suggest you take a good look and choose whatever you feel comfortable with or is similar to something you have worked on before.

Good luck my fellow Flutter developer, choose wisely :P

Comment: After reading your answer and other stuff on the internet, this seems like what I'm probably going to have to do...ugh. I wish I could have kept it cleaner. I just need to run one pesky little function from one widget to another and now I have to do all this lol!

Comment: If you just need to run it once, I think the least intrusive and less boilerplate could be using `provider`. Buuut it might depend on your setup. And yes, it kinda sucks that you may have to do the setup again and refactor a couple of things :/

Comment: Now I'm wondering if it's even useful to separate different parts of 1 screen into different widgets. I was taught that modularity should be the way to go most of the time because your code becomes more clean, but in this case it's adding an extra difficulty that doesn't really need to be there. If I were to just remove ChatScreen and combine ChatHeader and ChatFooter, then I wouldn't have this problem anymore...sorry for the rambling, just wanted to get these thoughts out of my brain lol

Comment: Oh, it's definitely useful, it makes the app scalable and your code easier to read. It's a common and healthy evolution of your code to jump from a single component into a much more complex widget tree. Don't be afraid to refactor code, it's normal. Usually, my apps start out simple but quickly turn into a much more complex one. My suggestion is always: Make it work, then make it better. I've written a couple of small tutorials on [how I structure apps with Bloc and Provider.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/32962047-bloc-8-0-tutorial-for-flutter-getting-started). You got this ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some event mechanism to notify `MessageDao` about an event in your app, e.g., `AudioRecordingStartedEvent`.

1. On `MessageDao` you subscribe on the event and stop the playing audio,
2. On `ChatFooter` you fire the event.

On pub.dev a lot of libraries that implement EventBus, e.g. [event_bus_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/event_bus_plus)